# How to signin Docusign

Tags: docusignapi, azure-logic-apps, power-automate

I would like to automate Docusign flow using Microsoft Logic Apps.

However, I cannot sign in my account such as below when I choose Docusign action in my Logic App.

Is it because my account is for Sandbox?

I tried changing the password and creating a new account to sign in, but they could not work.

[image: signinform]

Comment: I am facing the exact issue. Did you find any workarounds to connect Sandbox from Logic Apps.

Answer (score 2):

**This is solution I have implemented to trick the Docusign Connector**

- Use the Logic Apps Docusign production connector
- Sign in and create a connection to Production.
- Sign in to Docusign PROD Admin > Integrations > Connect > Newly created connection by Connector > Copy webhook URL > Disable
- Sign in to Docusign DEV Admin > Integrations > Connect > Create New connection with cloned properties > Paste webhook URL > Enable
- All DEV Docusign events will now be routed to the our Logic Apps connector (which thinks its connected to production).
- Downside : The actual completed envelope PDF cannot be retrieved as connector looks it inside the PROD environment (poor thing…its being tricked)

**======= UPDATE ======**

You can create a "*Logic Apps Custom Connector*" and configure DEV APIs to retrieve the completed documents from Docusign DEV.

Hopefully this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is production.
If you want to use demo, it's a little tricky, but you can do that too.
Follow this:
https://support.docusign.com/s/question/0D51W00006d0GKv/how-to-setup-the-connection-between-microsoft-flow-and-docusign-demo-environment
to connect the sandbox (demo) to Flow/Logic Apps

Comment: Hi,Inbar.
Thank you for your answer.

I tried this before, and Flow worked.
However, I couldn't find 'Docusign(demo)' in Logic Apps.

Does it work in Logic Apps?
Where should I add "? AddConnectorHideKey = DocuSignDemo" and press enter?

Comment: I am not sure about Logic Apps, I assumed that the connectors are independent of logic apps. Might be a question that Microsoft has to answer.

Comment: I am facing the exact issue. @Inbar Do you have any new updates as a workaround to connect Docusign Sandbox from Azure Logic Apps.

Comment: I saw you posted an answer, so this method of yours should be the workaround for now I'm afraid.